# Changing background color of several rows in rhandsontable

Tags: r, rhandsontable

Using

```
library("rhandsontable")
rhandsontable(data.frame(ID=1:5,var1=rnorm(5), var2=letters[1:5])) %>%    
hot_col(c(1,3), 
  renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.background = 'lightblue';
  }"
)
```

one can define the background color for selected columns, here columns 1 and 3.

Is it possible to do the same for selected rows?

This works if I directly reference the rows:

```
library("rhandsontable")
rhandsontable(data.frame(ID=1:5,var1=rnorm(5), var2=letters[1:5])) %>%
hot_cols(
  renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    if (row==1 || row==3 || row==4) td.style.background = 'lightblue';
  }"
)
```

However, I have the row indices in a vector that I would like to supply, something along these lines (which doesn't work, presumably becasue the renderer function can't see `myindex`):

```
myindex <- c(1, 3, 4)
rhandsontable(data.frame(ID=1:5,var1=rnorm(5), var2=letters[1:5])) %>%
hot_cols(
  renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    if (row in myindex) td.style.background = 'lightblue';}
  }"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient answer, but it works:
You can use `paste()`/`paste0()` to add your r object into the javascript code, like so:

```
myindex <- c(1, 3, 4)

rhandsontable(data.frame(ID=1:5,var1=rnorm(5), var2=letters[1:5])) %>%
  hot_cols(
    renderer = paste0(
      "
      function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
        var row_index = ", paste("[", paste(myindex, collapse = ","), "]"), ";
        for (i = 0; i < row_index.length; i++)
        if (row == row_index[i]) {
          td.style.background = 'lightblue';
        }
      }
      "
    )
  )
```

Comment: This solution also works inside a shiny app. There is also an alternative as `rhandsontable` now accepts a parameter, accessible via the `params` parameter. See the rhandsontable help under "Custom Renderer using an R Parameter" and the example provided there. But the above solution works equally well! Thanks!